# How many votes are required to trigger the vote abuse filter?

Tags: discussion, voting, abuse

How many votes does it take to trigger the vote abuse filter?  I ask because I just got 3 downvotes on three different answers at roughly the same time (on SO).  Artfully enough they all came on my answers that were already negative.  I suppose if you're going to downvote something, you might as well downvote the things that are bad.

Comment: I got suddenly 4 downvotes for question, which were not under zero. These were my first 4 downvotes in history. System didn't do anything.

Comment: this falls under the SOFU *don't-ask-won't-tell* policy.  don't ask, cause they won't tell.  (i'm pretty sure it's also a duplicate several times over.)

Comment: `<sarcasm>` Today has just been bad for my rep.  I'm going home. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: Heyyy, it's Beer:30!

Answer (score 3):

Jeff hasn't given details of the algorithm (because detailing anti-abuse measures is an invitation to circumvent them), but I'd imagine it takes a lot more than three votes to trigger it.

And why is it bad to downvote bad answers, anyway? Why would that be considered abuse?

Comment: Downvoting bad questions is one thing.  Downvoting a specific user's bad posts means you're targeting the user, not the post.

Comment: If I got them on three different days, I wouldn't care.  I have to admit I think it might have been a way of trying to avoid the filter.

Comment: @Pollyanna: No, that doesn't follow. Searching through posts by user is just another form of post selection. If you search for all posts tagged `fortran`, and downvote the bad ones, is that abuse? What if the bad ones are all by the same user? Why does SO make it easy to look at a user's post history, if you're not meant to vote on those posts? Abuse means downvoting answers that don't warrant them, with the intention of harming the reputation of the user. It's far from clear that this is the intention here.

Answer (score 0):

> How many votes does it take to trigger the vote abuse filter?

It's unlikely that you are going to get an exact answer to this question. and they may not even answer the real question:

> I just got three downvotes that are suspicious - will this trigger the vote-fraud detector, or must I contact a moderator?

Regardless, please flag one of the questions that was downvoted for moderator attention and note the situation so a moderator can take a look at it.